# Converting DateDiff and Count expressions from Access SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, count, datediff

Please, can someone help me with this part of query? It's working fine in Microsoft Access but won't work in MySQL:

```
DateDiff("m",[first_sent_date],[last_sent_date])+1 AS basetime_month, Count(tablename.id) AS cnt_all
```

Comment: You've got to translate your query to the sql dialect of MySQL. MySQL uses i.e. backticks to quote column names, functions are different too. The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The Access SQL [DateDiff](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx) function takes at least three (3) arguments. It returns different values based on the first argument, which is the "interval". In your case

```
DateDiff("m",[first_sent_date],[last_sent_date])
```

the `"m"` indicates that you want the difference in months.

The MySQL [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function only takes two (2) arguments and always returns the difference in days. The MySQL equivalent to the Access SQL `DateDiff` expression above would be something like

```
((YEAR(`last_sent_date`) - YEAR(`first_sent_date`)) * 12) + MONTH(`last_sent_date`) - MONTH(`first_sent_date`)
```